# What is the value of HSHELL_FLASH?

Tags: windows, hook, constants

What is the value of HSHELL_FLASH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant the actual integer value, `HSHELL_FLASH` is defined in WinUser.h as

```
#define HSHELL_FLASH (HSHELL_REDRAW | HSHELL_HIGHBIT)
```

where

```
#define HSHELL_REDRAW 6
#define HSHELL_HIGHBIT 0x8000
```

thus the actual value is `0x8006`.

Answer (score 0):

The value is 42.

Just kidding.

By "value" I'm assuming you're looking for a basic explanation of what this variable represents.  HSHELL_FLASH is a handle to a window that needs to be flashed.

HSHELL_FLASH should be treated similarily to HSHELL_REDRAW, except that you should redraw it in a flashed state (normally orange on the Explorer taskbar).  HSHELL_REDRAW means that either a window's title text has changed, or the window's icon has changed.

Comment: "HSHELL_FLASH is a handle to a window that needs to be flashed." is completely wrong. HSHELL_FLASH is an integer value which is passed as the wParam of a shell hook to indicate that a window has begun flashing. When wParam has that value, **lParam** is "A handle to the window that needs to be flashed."